# Change images dynamically inside a div within effect with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

1. I have four divs that hold images
2. I am using an effect that flips a card, this is currently working, [here is the fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fUsPh/7/)
   so you can see what I mean.
3. Now I would like to change the image for each div every time the user is over the image.
   To do this I created four arrays

   ```
   var arrFirstYellowCard = ["http://i.jootix.com/r/Flower-1920x1080.jpg", "http://7art-screensavers.com/screenshots/wet-flowers/incredible-orange-flower.jpg", "http://www.hdwallpapers.in/walls/big_yellow_flower-HD.jpg"];
   var arrSecondPurpleCard = ["http://www.dazzlewallpapers.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/07/Lotus-Flower-5.jpg", "hhttp://7art-screensavers.com/screenshots/wet-flowers/wet-violet-flower.jpg"];
   var arrThirdVectorFlower = ["http://0.tqn.com/d/rubberstamping/1/0/6/m/-/-/flower-outline.png", "http://openclipart.org/people/PeterM/PeterM_Flower_2.svg"];
   var arrfourthCrazyArt = ["http://www.bitrebels.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/11/electrocuted-flowers-robert-buelteman-1.jpg", "http://loadpaper.com/large/Flowers_wallpapers_251.jpg"];
   ```

for instance for the first div:

```
<section class="card-container">
    <div class="card over" data-direction="right">
        <div class="front">
            <h2>yellow flowers</h2>

            <h4>(Right)</h4>

        </div>
        <div class="back">
            <img src="CHANGE IMAGE DYNAMICALLY USING ARRAY arrFirstYellowCard" width="100%;" height="100%;" alt="" />
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

How would I dynamically change the image from the arrays for each div depending on if user is hovering over the card?

so the

1. first time users hovers the div changes first image in array and is displayed
2. second time users hovers the div, second image is changed by second image addres in array...

Please take a look at my fiddle. How would I add this functionality?

## UPDATE:

Following answer advices I have done:

```
var arrFirstYellowCard = ["http://7art-screensavers.com/screenshots/wet-flowers/incredible-orange-flower.jpg", "http://www.hdwallpapers.in/walls/big_yellow_flower-HD.jpg"];
var arrSecondPurpleCard = ["http://www.dazzlewallpapers.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/07/Lotus-Flower-5.jpg", "hhttp://7art-screensavers.com/screenshots/wet-flowers/wet-violet-flower.jpg"];
var arrThirdVectorFlower = ["http://0.tqn.com/d/rubberstamping/1/0/6/m/-/-/flower-outline.png", "http://openclipart.org/people/PeterM/PeterM_Flower_2.svg"];
    
        
$(function () {
    $('.over').hover(function () {
        
        if ($(this).attr('data-direction') == 'right') {
            $(this).addClass('flipping-right');
        }   
        if ($(this).attr('data-direction') == 'left') {
            $(this).addClass('flipping-left');
        }
        
    }, function () {
        if ($(this).attr('data-direction') == 'right'){    
            $(this).removeClass('flipping-right');
            var img = $(this).find('img');
            setTimeout(function() {
               img.attr('src', arrFirstYellowCard[i]);
               i++;
               if(i > arrFirstYellowCard.length-1)
                  i=0;
           }, 800);
        }
        if ($(this).attr('data-direction') == 'left'){    
            $(this).removeClass('flipping-left');
            var img = $(this).find('img');
            setTimeout(function() {
               img.attr('src', arrSecondPurpleCard[i]);
               i++;
               if(i > arrSecondPurpleCard.length-1)
                  i=0;
           }, 800);
        }
        
        
    });
})
```

But it does not seem to work, could someone help me out with this issuem [here is the fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fUsPh/28/)

Comment: Each card could store its array along with a counter on separate data attributes. When the user hovers increment the count and set the src attribute from the corresponding element in the array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find example of the requested functionality in updated [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/C7nNd/). I have left only one card for simplicity. I'm iterating in array, finding image in section and changing it's src attribute. The setTimeout is used to delay the change of src, to be sure that the card is flipped back and used doesn't see the change immediately.

The main part is:

```
var img = $(this).find('img');
img.attr('src', arrFirstYellowCard[i]);
```

and icrementing i on each call and changing back to 0 when it is more than the length of array.

Answer (score 1):

```
$(this).find('img').attr('src', arrFirstYellowCard[i]);
```

and increment `i` value